# How to extract the value from the <td> by using selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, beautifulsoup, webdriver

So i'm using selenium webdriver to parse date from web site by (class_name, tag_name, Xpath, css_selector) and all my attempts to fetch data are unsuccessful. And in this exapmple i'm trying with BS4. And all i get it's only text from "th". How to get text from "td"?

```py
driver.get(slot)
html = driver.page_source
soup  = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find_all('tr')
for x in table:
    print(x.get_text())`enter code here
```

html

```html
<table data-v data-qa="table" class"table">
   <tr data-v>
      <th data-v> Name </th>
      <th data-v> Last_name </th>
      <th data-v> Phone </th>
      <th data-v> City </th>
      <th data-v> Salary </th>
      </tr data-v>
   <tr data-v data-qa="table-row">
      <td data-v class="table-name not-editable">Tetyana</td>
      <td data-v class="table-last-name not-editable">Ferguson</td>
      <td data-v class="table-phone not-editable">252-823-1658</td>
      <td data-v class="table-city not-editable">Tarboro</td>
      <td data-v class="table-salary not-editable">10000</td>
      </tr data-v>
   <tr data-v data-qa="table-row">
      <td data-v class="table-name not-editable">Alyonka</td>
      <td data-v class="table-last-name not-editable">Andrews</td>
      <td data-v class="table-phone not-editable">603-608-7504</td>
      <td data-v class="table-city not-editable">Northwood</td>
      <td data-v class="table-salary not-editable">12000</td>
      </tr data-v>
</table>
```

Comment: I don't understand why you need to use the BeautifulSoup...simply use selenium to find your desired element (using some locator - in your case, xpath or classname) and then get the text of that element

Answer (score 0):

you have put "tr' in `soup.find_all('tr')` so you tr(table) header. if you put 'td' there then you will get td(row) data. When reading the table, you can also try pandas.read_html method which in many scenarios will be helpful.

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html_src="""
<table data-v data-qa="table" class"table">
   <tr data-v>
      <th data-v> Name </th>
      <th data-v> Last_name </th>
      <th data-v> Phone </th>
      <th data-v> City </th>
      <th data-v> Salary </th>
      </tr data-v>
   <tr data-v data-qa="table-row">
      <td data-v class="table-name not-editable">Tetyana</td>
      <td data-v class="table-last-name not-editable">Ferguson</td>
      <td data-v class="table-phone not-editable">252-823-1658</td>
      <td data-v class="table-city not-editable">Tarboro</td>
      <td data-v class="table-salary not-editable">10000</td>
      </tr data-v>
   <tr data-v data-qa="table-row">
      <td data-v class="table-name not-editable">Alyonka</td>
      <td data-v class="table-last-name not-editable">Andrews</td>
      <td data-v class="table-phone not-editable">603-608-7504</td>
      <td data-v class="table-city not-editable">Northwood</td>
      <td data-v class="table-salary not-editable">12000</td>
      </tr data-v>
</table>
"""
```

option 1:

```
df=pd.read_html(html_src)
print(df[0].head(10))
#output
 Name Last_name         Phone       City  Salary
0  Tetyana  Ferguson  252-823-1658    Tarboro   10000
1  Alyonka   Andrews  603-608-7504  Northwood   12000
```

option 2:

```
soup=BeautifulSoup(html_src)
for each in soup.find_all("td"):
    print(each.get_text())
#output:
Tetyana
Ferguson
252-823-1658
Tarboro
10000
Alyonka
Andrews
603-608-7504
Northwood
12000
```