# How to get text from <td> by using selenium or something else?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

When i open page source in Chrome i see all HTML code.

Here is HTML

```
<table data-v data-qa="table" class"table">
<tr data-v>
    <th data-v> Name </th>
    <th data-v> Last_name </th>
    <th data-v> Phone </th>
    <th data-v> City </th>
    <th data-v> Salary </th>
    <th data-v> ID </th>
    <th data-v> EXP </th>
    <th data-v> Current-Exp</th>
</tr data-v>

<tr data-v data-qa="table-row">

<tr data-v="" data-qa="table-row">
    <td data-v="" class="not-editable"><!----></td>
    <td data-v="" data-qa="name" class="not-editable"> Tetyana </td>
  
    <td data-v="" data-qa="table-last-name" class="not-editable"> Ferguson </td>
    <td data-v="" data-qa="table-phone" class="not-editable"> 252-823-1658 </td>
    <td data-v="" data-qa="table-city" class="not-editable"> Tarboro </td>
    <td data-v="" data-qa="table-salary" class="not-editable">
        <div data-v="" role="switch" aria-checked="true" aria-disabled="true" class="el-switch <!----></div>
    </td>
    <td data-v="" data-qa="table-id" class="not-editable no-shows-applied"> 1 
        <svg data-v=""  xmlns="http:XXXXX" viewBox="0 " class="svg-inline--fa"><path data-v="" fill="currentColor" d="1z" class=""></path></svg>
    </td>
    <td data-v="" data-qa="table-exp" class="not-editable"> 4 </td>
    <td data-v="" data-qa="table-current-exp" class="not-editable coverage-green"><span data-v="">1</span></td>
</tr>
```

But if i use command "driver.page_source" in my IDE i see only:

```
<table data-v data-qa="table" class"table">
<tr data-v>
    <th data-v> Name </th>
    <th data-v> Last_name </th>
    <th data-v> Phone </th>
    <th data-v> City </th>
    <th data-v> Salary </th>
    <th data-v> ID </th>
    <th data-v> EXP </th>
    <th data-v> Current-Exp</th>
</tr data-v>
</table>
```

I assumed it was  and tried using the command "driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_id('IFrame'))", but nothing worked either.

Comment: pls refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67257016/how-to-extract-the-value-from-the-td-by-using-selenium/67260273#67260273

Comment: I saw this before and using this method from this article, but it doesn't help me. @simpleApp

Comment: may i know which date you are trying to extract?

Comment: I suppose no, because this private website (sorry) @simpleApp

Comment: SO does not private page, but to debug or assist, need HTML to replicate or try. the HTML you have on this question, the solution I shared worked. so nothing much can help further.

Comment: @simpleApp I little change my question, maybe u can help now ?

Comment: It looks like the data rows are not being loaded in your selenium view. Do you need to add a step earlier in your selenium code making sure you log in or load the data or aything?

Comment: before you print driver.page_source, can you try to put some sleep and see if you get more on HTML ? `import time
time.sleep(10)`

Comment: @simpleApp Thank you so much. My problem was solved

Comment: great! you are welcome.